# Roslyn code-fix test calls `VerifyDiagnostics` also for fixed-code-sample, which makes test could never be successfull

Tags: c#, unit-testing, roslyn, code-analysis

---

**#UPD:** It was totally my mistake. Some details I've posted in my answer

---

Why does Roslyn code-fix test calls `VerifyDiagnostics` not only for test-source-code-sample, but then also for fixed-code-sample?

Unit tests of the Visual Studio template project "*Analyzer with Code Fix*" rely on such method:

```
public static async Task VerifyCodeFixAsync(
    /*1*/ string source, 
    /*2*/ DiagnosticResult[] expected, 
    /*3*/ string fixedSource)
{
    var test = new Test
    {
        TestCode = source,
        FixedCode = fixedSource,
    };

    test.ExpectedDiagnostics.AddRange(expected);
    await test.RunAsync(CancellationToken.None);
}
```

I understand arguments this way:

`/*1*/` - test code sample, with deliberate problems to test analyzer can find them

`/*2*/` - expecteds - special data about these deliberate problems (incl. location of each problem)

`/*3*/` - fixed code sample - it's what test code sample shoud became looks after applying auto-code fixing to it at places, analyzer have found

So, I expect `test.RunAsync` (called at last line) should work uder the hood in scenario similar to:

- 1st compare problems found by analyzer with `expecteds` - they should be equal
- 2nd apply auto-code fixing to the test-code-sample
- and finally compare code, produced by prev. step, with provided `fixedSource` (`/*3*/`)

And that's all I expect.

BUT! If you look at source code of class `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Testing.CodeFixTest<>` you could find such implementation of `RunAsync` method:

```
public override async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    ...
    await VerifyDiagnosticsAsync(new EvaluatedProjectState(testState, ...);  // <--- Line A

    if (CodeFixExpected())
    {
        await VerifyDiagnosticsAsync(new EvaluatedProjectState(fixedState, ...);  // <--- Line B
        ...
    }
}
```

It results in case of my analyzer to:

- If I pass **not-empty** `expected`, test fails at Line **B** with message:

> Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<**1**>. Actual:<**0**>. Context:
> Diagnostics of **fixed** state

'cos it looks like it somewhy compares problems found in fixed code sample to `expected` (which, I suppose is a mistake, as fixed code should not contain problems (by definition))

---

**#UPD:** Roslyn code is correct. It was my mistake - see at my posted answer.

---

- If I pass **empty** `expected`, Line B should be satisfied, but test fails (quite expected this time) at Line **A** with message:

> Assert.AreEqual failed. Expected:<**0**>. Actual:<**1**>. Context:
> Diagnostics of **test** state

So my question is: Why does Roslyn code-fix test compares `expected` to both (1st to test code sample, as completely expected as for me), but then to fixed code sample, which makes test could never be successfull?

Or maybe I'm missing something...

I would be grateful for any thoughts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.
It was my fault. By mistake I used `CSharpCodeFixVerifier` parametrized with another `AnalyzerCodeFixProvider` (not the one I should use there).

So, that 2nd call of `VerifyDiagnostics` (with fixed-code-sample as `state` argument) is correct. And, I guess, it checks that fixed-code-sample has no diagnosed problems.